# mono-xamarin.list Type 'sudo' is not known

Tags: linux-mint, apt, sudo, mono

Yesterday I installed monodevelop, had to write something in c#. It didn't (I couldn't build and run code) even worked, but fked everything, that I can't even install anything, can't type sudo, enter many files. Looks like I'm not logged as root?

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime
[sudo] password for krzy: 
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried many commands I found on ubuntu related forums, nothing helped

I'm using linux mint 18

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime  
sudo apt-get purge mono-complete  
sudo apt-get purge libmono* libgdiplus cli-common libglitz-glx1 libglitz1
```